# Traceback error in Python 1

Tags: python, traceback

I have this code:

```
import urllib.request
import json

import pickle

import time

class Weather:

    current_temp = 0

    def __init__(self):
        json_info = get_info()
        Weather.current_temp = k_to_f(((json_info['list'][0]['main']['temp'])))
        current_city = (json_info['list'][0]['name'])
        print ('Current temperature {0} degrees F in {1} '.format(Weather.current_temp, current_city))
        map = manage_file(current_city)

    def manage_file(self, current_city):
        read_f = open('temp.txt', 'rb')
        dict = pickle.load(read_f)
        read_f.close()
        dict[time.strftime('%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S ') + current_city] = Weather.current_temp
        write_f = open('temp.txt', 'wb')
        return dict

    def get_info(self):
        city = input("What city would you like the weather for? ")
        url = 'http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/find?q=' + city + 'mode=json'
        data = urllib.request.urlopen(url)
        data = data.read()
        json_info = json.loads(data.decode('UTF-8'))
        return json_info

    def k_to_f(self, num):
        num = (num-273.15)*1.8
        return round(num + 32, 2)
Weather()
```

and I am getting a traceback error of :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/httpnick/nicks_python/new_weather.py", line 36, in <module>
    Weather()
  File "/home/httpnick/nicks_python/new_weather.py", line 14, in __init__
    map = manage_file(current_city)
  File "/home/httpnick/nicks_python/weather.py", line 36, in manage_file
     def get_info(self):
NameError: global name 'current_temp' is not defined
```

Can anyone spot it? I have looked for a couple hours now...

Comment: As the traceback doesn't match your code (the last line is `def get_info(self):` this indicates you are running bytecode that's out of sync with your actual source. Restart python, and if that doesn't help, delete all `.pyc` files.

Comment: Is exact copy of your code? I would expect you to have an indentation error from the line `current_temp = 0`

Comment: The fact that 2/3rds the traceback references ``new_weather.py`` and 1/3rd references ``weather.py`` suggests that @MartijnPieters is correct.

Comment: Thanks guysWhere can I delete my .pyc files? And joconnor I manually indented that line after I copy and pasted my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing that stood out to me... is that you're not using the instance methods in the constructor.  You might try to make this explicit:

```
def __init__(self):
    json_info = self.get_info()
    ...
    map = self.manage_file(current_city)
```

(Also... I'd avoid naming a variable "map", as this is a builtin function.)

Comment: Okay so I changed every method call, and variable to "self.xxxx" (except for my one global varaible called current_temp I kept that Weather.current_temp). I am pretty new to python so I didn't really know I needed all the self. instantiations. I now got the error IOError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: 'temp.txt'  when I ran the line "write_f = open('temp.txt', 'wb')

Comment: I'm not sure why you're re-opening the file anyway... you don't actually use the write_f file descriptor anywhere (or close it).

Comment: oh I am sorry I forgot to add two lines that come right after the write_f line:                                        pickle.dump(dict,write_f)                                             write_f.close()